# Why my custom control referencing a .NET wrapper cannot be designed?

Tags: .net, user-controls, wrapper, design-time

Why I get the following error in the Visual Studio (2010) designer if a try to load the Form1 that hosts my custom control at design-time?

> Could not find type 'myCustomControl'. Please make sure that the assembly that    contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any CPU.
>   The variable 'myCustomControl1' is either undeclared or was never assigned.

It happens only when I add the reference to the .NET wrapper DLL (without referencing the .NET wrapper DLL the Visual Studio designer loads correctly). The windows form application works fine at run-time copying all the necessary wrapper's DLLs to side by side to application main assembly.

I suspect that the additional .NET wrapper DLLs are not copied when the custom control is used at design time. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: This is for VS2003, but worth a try...http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842706

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a C# template function containing a parameter of one of the types declared into the .NET wrapper DLL.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem could be that you're handling something if the Custom Control is in DesignMode. Please provide the Load code of your Custom Control to get further help.